# Retrofit response showing

Tags: android

I tried to post raw data to server using retrofit method, but I receive the failure response like res fail: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=500, message=Internal Server Error, url=http://192.168.1.9:8000/api/deviceinfo}

```
apiService = RetrofitSingleton.createService(ApiService.class);
spyApp = new SpyApp();
Call<ModelResponse> call  = apiService.eventsUpdate(jsonObj);
call.enqueue(new Callback<ModelResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ModelResponse> call, Response<ModelResponse> response) {
        Log.e("response", new Gson().toJson(response.body())); //This shows null
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            String status = response.body().getData().getStatus();
                           } else {
            Log.e("res fail", response.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ModelResponse> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e("failure",t.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Comment: check that api on postman first its working or what?

Comment: its because you are having issues at backend code 500 stands for internal server error probably your script has some issue in database or some similar issue

Comment: In postman It is working

Comment: check your input parameter keys